# Getting ID from array (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, drupal, ubercart

I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Sales
            [1] => Offices
            [2] => Products
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Cars
            [1] => Trucks
            [2] => Management
        )
)
```

All those 'Cars' 'Trucks' etc are links `<a href="/mysite/catalog/63">Cars</a>` etc. Now I would need to get that ID number of from those links? But Im pretty new to PHP and I have no idea how to get it. Foreach loop and reset function or something similar?

This is on drupal and ubercart if those info is needed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for a `foreach` loop with a `preg_match` *and* `explode()` to extract the ID:

```
$regex = '/href="([^"]+)/i';
foreach ($arr as $item) {
  foreach ($item as $html) {
    if (preg_match($regex, $html, $matches)) {
      $id = end(explode('/', $matches[1]));
      // For the string '<span class="field-content"><a href="/mysite/catalog/32">Cars/<a></span>' $id is equal to 32
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Clive. This is excactly what I was looking. Got the ID now :)

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
foreach($yourarry as $arr2){
    foreach($arr2 as $id=>$text){
        echo $id;
        echo $text;
    }
}
```

Comment: at this point $text = <a href="/mysite/catalog/63">Cars</a>. You'll need to explode() or regex to get the ID.

Comment: Thanks, got so far but having some trouble with xplode(). I noticed that it actually print some html too. Basically the $text is something like this: Cars (and the html for it: <span class="field-content"><a href="/mysite/catalog/32">Cars/<a></span>. How can I get that ID #32 from that?

Answer (score 0):

> a href="/mysite/catalog/63"

...implies that 63 is the id for Cars - but there is neither a key called id in your sample array nor a value of 63 - you can't write code to find a value which is not there.

If you want to extract the number from the link text, then have a look at the various string parsing functions, the easiest functions to use would be strtok, explode or preg_match.